# Make pager appear at top of listing

Tags: yii

In YII I have:

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider ($auctions , 
  array(
    'pagination'=>array(
      'pageSize'=> 12,
  ),
));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
  'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
  'itemView' => '_frontpageAuction',
  'summaryText' => '',
  'emptyText' => '
    No auctions available to display.
  ', 
));
```

How do I change it so the pager doesn't appear at the bottom of the grid, but rather at the top?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`template` property of CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#template-detail):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_frontpageAuction',
    'summaryText' => '',
    'emptyText' => '
          No auctions available to display.
    ',
    'template'=>'{pager}{items}' 
));
```

---

Also:

> These tokens are recognized: {summary}, {sorter}, {items} and {pager}. They will be replaced with the summary text, the sort links, the data item list, and the pager.

A similar property is available for [CGridView also: `template`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#template-detail).

Comment: changed code little bit, hadn't noticed that your summary text should be empty. so removed the {summary} token completely from the template.

Comment: I think my question was a bit vague. By default the pager appears BELOW a grid. I want it to appear at the TOP. How do I do that?

Comment: if you have tried my code(and it doesn't work for you), then i think we are talking about different pagers, can you show a screenshot, of which pager you are talking about?

Comment: Okay, it does work... but can you maybe explain to me why? Why would changing the copy of the pager move it to the top?

Comment: ofcourse, but what exactly do you mean by "copy of the pager"?

Comment: doesnt' template simply change the wording?

Comment: nope, template changes the way the listview is rendered, the order of the components that make up the listview, "the template to be used to control the layout of various components in the list view." .So that is just how listviews work in yii, before/while rendering/generating the content(html) the `template` property is read, and the "components" are placed accordingly, where this happens is in the `renderContent` [function](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#renderContent-detail)